# Change button from another view controller once the back button has been pressed

Tags: swift, swift4, xcode9.2

I'm trying to hide/disable a button from another view controller once the back button from a nav bar has been pressed, but I can't figure it out. Basically, I have a view controller where a user can add up to 7 days of workouts (days are displayed as buttons). Whenever they press on a day, they are taken to another view where they are able to select the exercises they wish to do during that day. Once they save and press the back button on the nav bar, I want to disable the button for the day they just added workouts for, so they can no longer press it. I would really appreciate your help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write the following code in the VC with a condition on back

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
 if appDelegate.isFromPreviousScreen == true{
    button.isHidden = true
   }
}
```

**Note:-** `fromPrevious` make it true when returning from nextVC

If your question is how to make `fromPrevious` true when leaving the secondVC:

Then you need to pass a value from there, Or to make that stuff easy as a beginner i would suggest you take a global Variable in `AppDelegate`

```
 class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    var isFromPreviousScreen:Bool = false
}
```

**And add the following code in SecondVC:**

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
       let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.isFromPreviousScreen = true
}
```

Hope this helps.